# how to choose table from a database that is selected with directory?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to get query with database address ?
for example :

```
SELECT *
FROM [C:\myDatabase.mdf].[dbo].[table1]
```

I mean how to choose database with directory ?
(also I don't want to use keyword "USE [database]" ...)

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: You cannot do this with SQL Server. In order to use the database from the **server-based** components, it has to be **attached** to the server. You cannot just specify a `.mdf` file and use it.

Comment: @lgor : I want to join two tables in two diffrent databases ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I  know you need this C:\myDatabase.mdf be used by the SQL server database service and served with a database name , could be MYDATABASE. I don't think the file path is ever exposed to/could be addressed from  SQL statement level